# Problems reading local files in a java applet

Tags: java, applet

I have been trying to read a file in from a local directory in my latest project. I'm passing into the function string "intro.txt" and while this reads ok in my IDE (JCreator) the file fails to read when running the applet html throwing the malformed URL exception.

```
public String readTextFile(String fileName) {
    String returnValue;
    String line;
    FileReader file = null;
    URL url = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(getCodeBase(), fileName);
    } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "failed to load local file!");
    }

    try {
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();

        while((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            strBuff.append(line + "\n");
        }

        returnValue = strBuff.toString();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: keep in mind when writing web applets that this kind of application is "invented" to run on many computers via internet. With this said, code, written by you, can run in any computer on this planet. That means that if you include some malicious I/O commands in your code (delete file commands for example), they would run in a computer just by "seeing" the html that embeds your applet, and do some damage. So, java designers, to ensure that this thing won't happen almost disabled I/O from applets. You can perfectly use I/O with swing or awt applications but not applets...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You d'ont have the rignt to access the file system of the visitors of your website (users of your applet). To be able to do this you have to sign your applet, and the user will be warned that you want to access his file system. Only if he accepts to let you in you'll be able to read files.

Here's a good link to start your bug resolving
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: *"You d'ont have the rignt to access the file system of the visitors of your website"*  Misleading!  `new URL(getCodeBase(), fileName);` Could hardly be pointing to a `File` on the end user's file system (unless the developer was also the end user).  It should be fine to work as an applet on the internet.  I *suspect* the problem would be solved by loading the HTML from a local server or direct from a site on the internet, rather than as a file based URI. -1 for this completely wrong answer.

Comment: Ok you're right, I was myself misleaded with the error message: "failed to load local file!". 
Then the answer is to read the file either as a jar resource or to grab it from a website.